Creating group or menu of multiple plugins in QGIS
I will create a bundle of plugins (one is already created). Instead of storing each plugin loosely as a single plugin, I would like to have them stored in a group, similar to a menu like this:

How can I create a group for plugins (which are NOT created based on the processing template)?

What you've shown in the embedded image is the Processing Toolbox, which is a QDockWidget containing a QTreeView showing the installed processing algorithms in a tree-structured menu. You should not add regular plugins to the Processing Toolbox. You could create your own Dock Widget and add your plugins to a list widget of some kind embedded in that. The Plugin Builder plugin provides an option to create a plugin with a Dock Widget, which will get you started.
Another option would be to add a new menu entry to the main QGIS menu or as a submenu to one of the existing QGIS menus. The Plugin Builder provides options to add as submenu for your plugin to the Raster, Vector, Database, Web, or Plugins menu. One approach would be to create a main plugin that creates the menu and then have your other plugins add themselves to the main plugin's menu rather than creating their own menus.
Yet another option would be to add a menu button to the QGIS took bar and add your widgets to that button's popup menu.
Basically, your plugins can create any kind of interface supported by Qt, the GUI framework QGIS is based on, which gives you a lot of freedom and any number of ways to do something like you are describing. Looking at the source code for other plugins and at how they do what they do can be very instructive.
